# Creating inputs dynamically from a hash with simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, simple-form

I have a `Configuration` model which stores `settings` in a JSONB column.

```
# Stores site wide configuration settings
# This is used in conjunction with PaperTrail to make each change traceable
class Configuration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  after_initialize :default_values if :new_record?

  private
  def default_values
    self.settings = {
        site_title: 'Portfolio Site'
    }
  end
end
```

The models sets up certain default attributes such as `site_title`. I want to use the settings hash to dynamically create inputs in my form. I have tried:

```
= simple_form_for(@configuration) do |f|
  = f.input :name

  = simple_fields_for :settings do
    - @configuration.settings.each do |k,v|
      = f.input k

  = f.submit
```

Which gives `undefined method 'site_title'` as it's not a model attribute. Can I use simple_forms `input` method while specifying the key and value binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually as simple as creating a Proxy object or Decorator for the hash - which acts like a model.

```
class SettingsDecorator

  INPUT_TYPES = {
      some_number: :integer
  }

  # @see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html
  MODEL_NAME = ActiveModel::Name.new(self.class, nil, 'settings')

  # @see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html
  def model_name
    MODEL_NAME
  end

  def initialize(hash)
    @object = hash.symbolize_keys
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    if @object.key? method
       @object[method]
    elsif @object.respond_to? method
       @object.send(method, *args, &block)
    end
  end

  def has_attribute? attr
    @object.key? attr
  end

  def input_type? key
    INPUT_TYPES[key]
  end
end
```

Simple Form tries to lookup the column for each input but will gracefully fallback to `:text` if the object does not respond to `column_for_attribute`.

I can then use it like so:

```
= simple_form_for(@configuration) do |f|
  = f.input :name
  - settings = SettingsDecorator.new(@configuration.settings)
  = simple_fields_for settings do |sf|
    - settings.keys.each do |key|
      = sf.input key, as: settings.input_type?(key)
  = f.submit
```

Comment: A more complete writeup https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-inputs-for-key-value-hash-attributes.

Answer (score 2):

doesn't look like you can use `simple_form` for non-attribute inputs. This will work though:

```
= simple_form_for(@configuration) do |f|
  = f.input :name

  - @configuration.settings.each do |k,v|
    = text_field_tag "configurations[settings][#{k}]", v 

  = f.submit
```

You could probably expand the value of the defaults settings to also include the input type you'd like to render via `array`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already knew I could use Rails built in form helper. The reason I want to use simple form is most of all that I don't want to duplicate my basic input markup. I'm currently looking into creating a decorator object that quacks like a model.